# Python 3.x Trying to input a DF column and it's location

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to define a function. I want to pass a df.[['cols']] and it's location. I am pretty sure there is an easier way to do what I want, but the goal is to train a linear regression model, and replace all the NULL locations with a best guess. It is not actually my goal to test the accuracy of the model, just use it blind, so maybe my test train split code is wrong.

in [133]:

```
def impute(cols, colID):
    toBeImputed = cols[0]
    Y = toBeImputed.dropna()

    X = d.drop(colID, axis=1) # use all the columns but the colpassed as X aka predictors

    trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0) 

    linReg = linear_model.LinearRegression()

    # Use this model to predic Y by using Data i.e., testX
    linReg.fit(trainX, trainY)

    if pd.isnull(toBeImputed):
        return linReg.predict(toBeImputed)

    else:
        return toBeImputed
```

in [134]:

```
df['bedrooms'] = (df[['bedrooms']], 9).apply(impute,axis=1)
```

> out[134]:
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 df['bedrooms'] = (df[['bedrooms']], 9).apply(impute,axis=1)
>
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: do `df['bedroom'].apply(impute, colID=9)`?

Comment: Alright, I get
'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'dropna'